# How to obtain the compilation date of an exe from a Linux command line

Tags: linux, compilation, executable

Given a windows exe, how would I obtain the compilation date (not the creation date) for that exe from a Linux command line?

EDIT: I was able to get the information I needed, though not from a Linux command line.  On a Windows box [Get compilation Date & Time from .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212518/get-compilation-date-time-from-exe) would work, though I ended up using PEView under Wine: http://wjradburn.com/software/ .

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer since I'm just guessing myself, but are you maybe looking for a PE dumper, like https://github.com/zed-0xff/pedump or https://linux.die.net/man/1/winedump?

Comment: I'm building a reference list of patches to a game client.  For a few versions, I have a copy of the patched client, but no patch notes were released, and noone wrote down what date it was released.  So I'm hoping to at least get within a day of the right day using the compilation date for that particular patch's client build.

Answer (score 0):

There is some date there that looks like a compilation date:

```
LANG=C objdump -x program.exe | grep Time/Date
```